# How to apply styles with a component called

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I have a filter component that I am importing into my app component that has default styles, but I want each component to have a different style depending on the need, but when I apply a class in app.component.scss, it is not applied, it always shows the filter.component originals, what can I do?

My component called

```
<is-filter class="bgWhite" [type]="'verdicts'" [filterObj]="filterObj" (onFilter)="filter($event)"></is-filter>
```

My custom styles app.component

```
.bgWhite {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

My custom styles filter.component

```
<div class="card-footer pt-0 pb-3 filter-container" id="filter">
  ...
</div>

SCSS:
card-footer {
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

Comment: Try to set viewEncapsulation to none in your app.component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to gerenerally overwrite the styles of the imported component you can do it in the global `styles.scss`. This is a fitting solution in your project if you want to have the same overwritten styles for the imported components.

If you want to change the styles from the parent components of the imported components you can whether choose the `ViewEncapsulation` with `None` value (as MikeOne mentioned in the comment) or you can use `::ng-deep`. Last one is deprecated so I would not go for that.

[ViewEncapsulatation docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation), [ng-deep docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).